# Third party admin access in AWS via OAuth

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, amazon-iam

Is there a way to grant admin access to a third party in AWS without manually creating IAM role etc, purely via OAuth flow or similar?

Context: making an app that simplifies AWS account management, and want to make the UX to "connect to my account" as simple as possible. Failed to find anything like that in AWS docs. Want the app to be able to provision and manage resources, run terraform etc.

Comment: What type of third-party would this be? Something running on an AWS instance? Something coming completely external to AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: [Identity Providers and Federation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers.html). You will still have to create pre-defined IAM roles to define what permission users will assume

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's doable.  You do need to create IAM roles,  if you want to give your users access to everything just create an admin role with permissions of '*:*' on all resources.

Then you should set up some type of SAML server,  active directory federation services comes with everything out of the box.  You can look for some open source SAML servers.

Then you have to setup SAML federation between your user account and your SAML backend.